# IIS7, Default.aspx error message (screenshot)

Tags: windows-7, iis, server-error

I'm creating a new ASP.net website via Visual Studio.  I then try to run the default.aspx page it generates, and it throws this error:

[image]

I've tried deleting the affected lines as suggested by [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942055) but to no avail!  I am on Windows 7, with ASP.net installed

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common error when you assign the Site (that includes a web.config from .net 3.5) to an application pool that is running in 4.0. It causes some of the entries in web.config to be duplicated, so you can: 1) clean up the web.config to remove those duplicated entries, or 2) change the application pool to one that is using .net 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly have you tried to delete? The MSDN article about the specific error code `0x8020700b7` talks about deleting duplicate entrys in the ApplicationHost.config file. But your error message postet above talks about the web.config which are two completely different files as far as I know.

The marked line 15 should be in the web.config. where the marked duplicate entry should be.